# Modify GroovyDSL classpath to include 3rd party libraries

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, classpath, groovydsl

I'm trying to create a GroovyDSL script which references some external libraries. Here's my script:

```
import com.github.javaparser.ast.Node
import org.reflections.Reflections

def ctx = context(
        ctype: 'groovy.util.ObjectGraphBuilder',
        paths: ['com/example/scripts/.*'],
        filetypes: ["groovy"]
)

Map<String, Class> candidateClasses = new Reflections(Node.packageName).getSubTypesOf(Node)
        .collectEntries { Class type -> [(type.simpleName.uncapitalize()): type] }

contributor(ctx) {
    candidateClasses.each { String methodName, Class type ->
        method name: methodName, params: [props: "java.util.Map", closure: "groovy.lang.Closure"], type: type.name
    }
}
```

Trying to enable it in Intellij, I'm getting:

> startup failed: transformDslSyntaxgdsl: 1: unable to resolve class com.github.javaparser.ast.Node
>
> @ line 1, column 1.
>
> import com.github.javaparser.ast.Node

Now, I have the proper external dependencies declared in `pom.xml`, the rest of the code that depends on them is working just fine. I've also put the script inside a source folder (which some other answers here suggested might be relevant).

I have seen some examples for GDSL reference Intellij types like `PsiClass`, which tells me the classpath for GDSL files seems to be different from the project classpath. Is there any way to make sure project dependencies are appended to that classpath?

I also tried using `@Grape` only to get [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62439105/groovy-grab-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-ivy-plugins-resolver-dependencyres). Adding Apache Ivy as a dependency doesn't help, because again, project dependencies don't seem to influence the GDSL classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more digging, I found that it is pretty easy to modify the IDE's classpath itself.

All you need to do is to drop a dependency into Intellij installation directory's `lib` subfolder, and reference the jar inside `classpath.txt`.

Initially, I added the jars my GDSL depends on directly, but then I realized I could simply add a dependency on Apache Ivy to `classpath.txt` instead and `@Grab` annotations would start working.